# Muliple collections as input of mongodb for hadoop map-reduce job

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am trying to pass multiple collections as input for performing map-reduce hadoop job.
 I found MultiCollectionSplitBuilder in version 1.2 has the capability. The following example is posted in github which is not working any help is appreciated.

```
 MultiCollectionSplitBuilder mcsb = new MultiCollectionSplitBuilder();
        mcsb.add(new MongoURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.in"),
                 (MongoURI)null, // authuri
                 true, // notimeout
                 (DBObject)null, // fields
                 (DBObject)null, // sort
                 (DBObject)null, // query
                 false,
                 MultiMongoCollectionSplitter.class)
            .add(new MongoURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.in"),
                 (MongoURI)null, // authuri
                 true, // notimeout
                 (DBObject)null, // fields
                 (DBObject)null, // sort
                 new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("$gt", new Date(883440000000L))),
                 false, // range query
                 MultiMongoCollectionSplitter.class);

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(MultiMongoCollectionSplitter.MULTI_COLLECTION_CONF_KEY, mcsb.toJSON());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the example code is "not working" for you? Is there a specific error message, is the outcome not what you expected, ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this issue. It is an error in the example. [HADOOP-109](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-109) has been filed to fix this issue.

I fixed the issue by making the sub-splitter classes as `null` for all input collections. See [this pull request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/pull/93).

For you to make it work, ensure you pass the following parameter to Hadoop:

```
-D mongo.splitter.class=com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MultiMongoCollectionSplitter
```

This above fix is a workaround. Giving you more details about the problem. By design, the sub-splitter class could be any splitter class except `MultiMongoCollectionSplitter`. But there is a bug [HADOOP-110](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-110) that prevents us from doing that. This issue will be fixed soon in future release.